# Android. Opening a contact in through intent using contact_id or contact_name

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using ContactsContract API in Android to get the list of contacts. The is working fine.

Now I want that when I click on a name in that list an intent is generated that will open the contact in the android contact manager.

```
The following code crashes the app:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI + "/" + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
```

kindly help me out here with this intent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should show the contacts 'card' in the android contact manager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
intent.setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact")` - if there are several applications applicable for showing contact then user will see chooser dialog with list of the applications. If you use `intent.setData(uri)` then chooser won't be shown.